# Pandas Dataframe object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object-type

I have a large dataframe, ~ 1 million rows and 9 columns with some rows missing data in a few of the columns.

```
dat = pd.read_table( 'file path', delimiter = ';')

I        z        Sp   S        B        B/T     r        gf      k
0        0.0303   2    0.606    0.31     0.04    0.23     0.03    0.38   
1        0.0779   2             0.00     0.00    0.05     0.01    0.00
```

The first few columns are being read in as a string, and the last few as `NaN`, even when there is a numeric value there. When I include `dtype = 'float64'` I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Any help in fixing this?

Comment: is every value a float number?

Comment: @Ika8 yes they are

Comment: try with dtype = object

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by regex - one or more `whitespaces` to `NaN`, then cast to `float`

Empty strings in data are converted to `NaN` in `read_table`.

```
df = df.replace({'\s+':np.nan}, regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
     I       z   Sp      S     B   B/T     r    gf     k
0  0.0  0.0303  2.0  0.606  0.31  0.04  0.23  0.03  0.38
1  1.0  0.0779  2.0    NaN  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.01  0.00
```

If data contains some strings which need be replaced to `NaN` is possible use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `apply`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
print (df)
   I       z  Sp      S     B   B/T     r    gf     k
0  0  0.0303   2  0.606  0.31  0.04  0.23  0.03  0.38
1  1  0.0779   2    NaN  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.01  0.00
```

Comment: The last three columns are being read in all as NaN when they all have values. It works for the first 6 though.

Comment: Do you use `df.replace({'\s+':np.nan}, regex=True).astype(float)` or `to_numeric` solution? Are data in 3 last columns numeric?

Comment: The first solution did not work, the second was the one that returned NaN for the last three columns, which are numeric.

Comment: Ok, is possible some numeric starts or ends with empty spaces in last 3 columns?

Comment: If yes, this should works `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.astype(str).str.strip(), errors='coerce'))`